# Horizontally center an element with the editor

Tags: feature-request, editor, information-display

Simple question, is it possible to horizontally center an element for example an image or a heading in a post with the editor?

If not would you consider adding this feature to the editor?

Comment: Looking at the allowed html I would say: No that is not possible: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: No, there is no way to center anything in a post, with the editor or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

In fact, [Markdown itself](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (which is primarily used for formatting on SE) doesn't support any horizontal positioning.

(And, as noted in the comments, there are no center-positioning tags in the [allowed HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/) either.)